# Migrating from VB6 to .NET, is there an equivalent function for TreeNode.FirstSibling?

Tags: vb.net, vb6, treeview, vb6-migration

The desktop application I'm migrating makes heavy use of a TreeView control, and many calls to `TreeNode.FirstSibling`, e.g.

```
'UPGRADE_ISSUE: MSComctlLib.Node property tvTreeView.SelectedItem.FirstSibling was not upgraded.
If tvTreeView.SelectedNode.FirstSibling.Index = 1 Then
...
End If
```

Is there an equivalent function to use?

Comment: Im assuming VB6 had the index of the first node be 1? (not zero based) Then wouldnt the above IF statement ALWAYS be true?

Comment: I think you're right! But its not the only use of it so the problem remains even after removing those sort of programming mistakes.. Maybe I should have re-written from scratch..

Comment: @brass - Read this if you're thinking about re-writting 
http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well to have a sibling it has to have a parent, so you could do

```
myTreeNode.Parent.FirstNode
```

Or you could do

```
myTreeNode.Parent.Nodes[0]
```

**EDIT:** and for last sibling:

```
myTreeNode.Parent.LastNode
```

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but isn't  "FirstChild", or FirstParent. Alternatively, NextNode, which should iterate through siblings.